# My signs aren't changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS just playing around to understand how it works.

Why isn't my sign (+,-) changing?
When the div expand it remains with a + sigh never goes to -

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($(".expanderSign").text() == "+"){
            $(".expanderSign").html("−")
        }
        else {
            $(".expanderSign").text("+")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show the html script as well?

Comment: Just from a quick look, change `.text()` to `.html()`.

Comment: Can you demonstrate it in a fiddle?

Comment: You should probably at least pick either `.text()` or `.html()` and use one or the other consistently.

Comment: Is there more than one element with class `expanderSign`? Your code examines all of them and updates them all, not just the one connected to the `expanderHead` that you clicked on.

Comment: @Googly To expand on Barmar's comment, in case you're not familiar with fiddles, you should put that JavaScript and the relevant HTML into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Or you could use jquery accordion and have it handled automatically

Comment: I put in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bEkZd/. I also changed everything to html. Yes its looking at all of them, I have no idea how to fix, any help will be appreciated. Thanks>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing at the relationship, since you haven't shown your HTML, but you probably need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expanderHead:visible").click(function () {
        var content = $(this).next(".expanderContent");
        var sign = $(this).find(".expanderSign");
        if (content.is(":visible")) {
            content.slideUp();
            sign.text("+");
        } else {
            var expanded = $(".expanderContent:visible");
            if (expanded.length > 0) {
                expanded.slideUp();
                expanded.prev(".expanderHead").find(".expanderSign").text("+");
            }
            content.slideDown();
            sign.text("-");
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bEkZd/10/)

Comment: Sorry same result..Thanks>

Comment: Works fine in your fiddle if you change `.prev` to `.find` and select the jQuery framework. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bEkZd/4/

Comment: thanks that worked.. If its not too much bother can you show me how to auto collapse one div if I click on another.

Comment: You could get rid of a lot of that code by calling `$(".expanderContent:visible").slideToggle();` first in your click event then doing the rest

Comment: @jesus.tesh But it also has to toggle the +/- on that DIV when it slides it. And you have to do something different depending on whether the one that's visible is the same one you clicked on. I went through several iterations, this gets everything right and seems clear.

Comment: @Barmar - Yep, good point - I did not think about that. You could use `each` and tighten it up a bit, but then again sometimes more verbose code is better to teach with. :)